# List (of T) and Eval

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using a List(of T) in my VB.Net/ASP.Net project. While displaying the list on ASP.net, I am using #Eval, but my date (After formattin) is always displaying the MinVal insteaad of Null Spacs. How to check for date.min on #Eval to get the date as " " when its equal to Date.Min Val

Answer (score 0):

DateTime object can not be Null by default until you define it Nullable. If you want DateTime object to be able to hold null as value then you need to define the object data type as Nullable and explicitly assign Null. By default, any DateTime object is assigned the Min value. 
If you want to check if date has Min value, either you can user DateTime.MinValue property or create a new DateTime object (It will be assigned Min value by default) then compare with that object.

[Example]

```
Public Property MyDate As DateTime?


' get value
<asp:someElement attr='<%# If(Eval("MyDate") Is Nothing, " ", CType(Eval("MyDate"), DateTime?).Value.ToShortDateString()) %>'></asp:someElement>
```